# Are questions about the scientific basis of mythology on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This is inspired by https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/435/how-enkidu-was-created-out-of-clay-and-saliva, which (to my understanding) discusses the scientific basis behind a myth. [My opinion](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/435/how-enkidu-was-created-out-of-clay-and-saliva#comment1555_435) was

> I'm downvoting only because it asks about the feasiblity of a myth. Any and all myths are impossible in some way.

"All" is a poor choice of words on my part, but I think it gets the sentiment across. We could come up with questions along this line for many, many, many myths.

Currently, the question has two close votes; both are "unclear what you're asking." I have not yet voted to close because I want to put this question on meta first.

Are feasibility questions on or off topic? I would vote, by the way, for "off topic".

Comment: Related: http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/21/are-questions-about-the-relationship-between-history-and-mythology-on-topic (It's **decidedly not** a duplicate), but the same reasoning may apply.

Comment: Aside: that question is certainly not "unclear about what is being asked". Whether it's on-topic or not is a different story.

Comment: This is exactly same thing I was asking in [this post](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/103/)  (Although perhaps this one is phrased better because it's more specific)

Comment: @DavidStratton I saw that afterword; I wanted to address both the question I brought up and something more general than just abilities, although the answers there addressed that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it depends heavily on how the question is phrased.

- An "out-of-universe" feasibility question, such as:

> In reality, can a human be created out of clay and saliva?

is blatantly off-topic. These sorts of questions belong on the Worldbuilding, Physics, Biology, Chemistry, or some other SE depending on the exact content.

- An "in-universe" variation of the question could be on-topic. For example:

> Wikipedia states that "Enkidu was formed from clay and saliva by
>   Aruru." Do we know any more detail about this process? Did Aruru
>   sculpt him like a potter, or did she spit on the clay and cast a spell
>   of some sort? Is there any particular reason she chose these materials?

I'm not sure if this would be *answerable*, or if there is an answer other than "we don't know," but at least this way it seems unambiguously on-topic to me. Maybe that last part could spur some interesting answer about the symbolic meanings of clay and saliva.

---

Looking at the main site question, I think it leans far more toward the former/out-of-universe question, and is thus off-topic in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the linked question appears off-topic as it asks for (pseudo)scientific validation of the creation of beings.

If the question was wider, allowing for answers that are purely mythological - such as *Aruru chewed the clay and spat Enkidu out whole* then it is on-topic.

There is a very blurred line between the two.  At this stage of the genesis of this site we should aim to improve the focus steadily.